# Can I check if mouse is still hovered?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using Google's info window.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function(clicked) {
            info.setContent(self.createInfoWindowFor(attr, refs));
            info.open(self.map, this);
});
```

On mouseover, a new tooltip box is appeared. What I want to do is to check mouse is still hovered in every 5secs lets say. If not, close the infobox. How can I do that?

Comment: The `mouseout` event?

Comment: I think alex is saying that on moseover open the tooltip box and keep it open until the mouseout event is fired, which closes the tooltip box

Comment: exactly! That's what i want

Comment: check i have posted the sample how to do on mouse over and mouseout

Comment: @NadeemmnnMohd Your answer was ok, but ideally you should explain what it does. It's on great consensus that [code only answers are bad](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148272), so maybe you can fix it to explain what you've done, even if it's simple. Remember that SO is visited by people of all skill levels. The code is [readable enough to not warrant a flag](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95470/), but I still think a little explanation would be beneficial, even if just saying *"add a mouseout event: <the code>"*.

Answer (score 0):

```
 google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function() {
    infowindow.open(map,marker);
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseout', function() {
    infowindow.close(map,marker);
  });
```

Mouseover and mouseout if you just want to show popup on marker over and marker out

Comment: that's not what i want buddy.